# Para que servem as [ ] em bash?

Tags: if, bash, shell, shell-script, condição

Estou iniciando em shell script agora, e frequentemente, lendo programas de outras pessoas, vejo a utilização de `[]` associado ao `if`. Por exemplo:

```
if [condition]; then

fi
```

Já vi muitas vezes também a utilização da seguinte forma:

```
if [[condition]]; then

fi
```

Ainda não entendi muito bem a finalidade destes caracteres... Queria entender exatamente como isso funciona e quando devo utilizar em meus scripts.

Alguém sabe me explicar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ambos [`[`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html#LEFTBRACKET) e [`[[`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html#DBLBRACKETS) são usados para avaliar o que estiver entre `[..]` ou `[[..]]`, pode-se comparar *strings* e verificar os tipos de arquivo.

`[` é um sinônimo para  [`test`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/test), `[[` é uma [palavra-chave](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internal.html#KEYWORDREF).

Ao fazer `if [ condicao ]` pode-se dizer equivalente a `if test condicao`, pois `[` é um [*token*](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html#FTN.AEN3140) que vai invocar o comando `test`.

O colchete direito `]`, não é estritamente necessário, no entanto em versões mais recentes do [Bash](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BASH) é exigido.

```py
~$ type test
test is a shell builtin
~$ type '['
[ is a shell builtin
~$ type '[['
[[ is a shell keyword
~$ type ']]'
]] is a shell keyword
~$ type ']'
bash: type: ]: not found
```

`[[..]]` é mais flexível que `[..]`, ao usar `[[..]]` pode-se evitar alguns erros de lógica no *script*. Por exemplo, os operadores `&&`, `||`, `<`, e `>` funcionam no `[[..]]`, mas não em `[..]`.

Veja um exemplo:

```bash
if [ -f $foo && -f $bar && -f $baz ]          # Erro

if [ -f $foo ] && [ -f $bar ] && [ -f $baz ]  # OK. Cada expressão dentro de um [..] 
if [ -f $foo -a -f $bar -a -f $baz ]          # OK. Tem que usar "-a" na antes da expressão

if [[ -f $foo && -f $bar && -f $baz ]]        # OK!
```

---

A diferença e quando e qual usar entre `[` e `[[` segundo o [BashFAQ - **031**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031) é:

> To cut a long story short: `test` implements the old, portable syntax of
>   the command. In almost all shells (the oldest [Bourne shells](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BourneShell) are the
>   exception), `[` is a synonym for `test` (but requires a final argument of
>   `]`).
>
> Although all modern shells have *built-in* implementations of `[`,
>   there usually still is an external executable of that name, e.g. `/bin/[`.
>
> `[[` is a new improved version of it, which is a keyword, not a program.
>   This has beneficial effects on the ease of use, as shown below.
>
> `[[` is understood by [KornShell](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/KornShell) and [BASH](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BASH) (e.g. *2.03*), but not by the older POSIX or [Bourne shell](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BourneShell).
>
> [....]
>
> **When should the new test command `[[` be used, and when the old one `[`**?
>
> If portability to the BourneShell is a concern, the old syntax should
>   be used. If on the other hand the script requires [BASH](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BASH) or [KornShell](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/KornShell),
>   the new syntax is much more flexible.

Embora `[` e `[[` têm muito em comum e compartilham muitos operadores de expressão como `-f`, `-s`, `-n`, `-z`, existem algumas diferenças notáveis.

Aqui está uma lista de comparação:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

<sub>**Créditos**: [BashFAQ - **031**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Em resumo: O *[ ]* funciona da mesma forma que o *( )*.

Uma boa explicação sobre isso pode ser vista no site [Programando em shell script](http://www.devin.com.br/shell_script/).

> Controle de fluxo são comandos que vão testando algumas alternativas,
>   e de acordo com essas alternativas, vão executando comandos. Um dos
>   comandos de controle de fluxo mais usados é certamente o if.
>
> ```
> if [ -e $linux ]
> then
>   echo 'A variável $linux existe.'
> else
>   echo 'A variável $linux não existe.'
> fi
> ```
>
> O if testa a seguinte expressão: Se a variável $linux existir, então
>   (then) ele diz que que existe com o echo, se não (else), ele diz que
>   não existe. O operador -e é pré-definido, e você pode encontrar a
>   listagem dos operadores na tabela:
>
> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Referência: [Programando em shell script](http://www.devin.com.br/shell_script/)

Answer (score 1):

Isso é um teste de condição.

Por exemplo:

```
if [ -e arq.txt ]; then
   echo Arquivo existe
else
   echo Arquivo nao existe
fi
```

vai mostrar a mensagem "Arquivo existe" ou a mensagem "Arquivo nao existe", dependendo de o arquivo "arq.txt" existir no diretório corrente.

Também pode ser usado o colchete duplo:

```
if [[ -e arq.txt ]]; then
   echo Arquivo existe
else
   echo Arquivo nao existe
fi
```

mas existem algums diferenças entre colchete simples e colchete duplo. A grosso modo, o colchete duplo tem mais recursos.

Para ver as diferenças entre o uso de colchete simples e colchete duplo o melhor mesmo é ver a documentação (man bash) ou fazer uma pesquisa na internet, vai ter muita coisa (mas quase tudo em inglês).